Facebook login unavailable due to incomplete business verification status
We're encountering an issue with our android and ios app that uses Facebook login. It was working fine and suddenly it has stopped working now and we see the error: "facebook login is currently unavailable for this app".
Upon digging further, we found that the business verification status is now "Incomplete" and when we try to submit documents using any of the mentioned methods, it is always giving an error: "We're sorry, but there's a technical problem with this feature. We're working to fix it."
It has been in this state for 3 days now and our users are getting affected because of this.
Any idea what can be done to fix this. Is there a way to directly contact the support team to resolve this issue?
[Update 1] Since uploading documents was not working, we decided to create a new business account and submitted the documents using that. For some reason, that worked. However, the documents are in review now for a week. We had submitted on 27th April 2024, and after a week, it is still in review. The app is still giving the same error "Facebook login is not available for this app".
Thank you.

create configuration for the application and add config_id in request uri.

As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
